# Using Fitnesse to test external data

Tags: fitnesse, acceptance-testing, user-acceptance-testing

We would like to use Fitnesse to test externally produced data set. Specifically, the tests would contain invariants that must be valid in the data, but every time tests are run they would fetch the data from, let's say, a database and apply the checks to every row in the result set.

The tests would still be organised as wiki pages, but each one once running would be repeated for all applicable data rows. Should a particular row fail an assertion, we still want the tests to continue for other rows, but then receive a summary and a list of rows failed each particular assertion.

I understand this is not exactly what Fitnesse is for, but we do have skills in the team to write fixtures and tests, and we like the idea of haivng non-technical subject matter experts authoring some of the tests.

Is there a way of achieveing the above in Fitnesse, or is it completely outside of its intended usage? If it is possible, I would appreciate any guidance on how to achieve that, I couldn't find anything insightful in the documentation (or other websites).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [Slim](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM) protocol is what you're looking for to write the fixtures.
The [Query Table](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.QueryTable) in particular.